# Why does "Copy" replace stuff instead of merging it?

Tags: finder, uti

This is started to be really **annoying** to me

If you have an original folder with 2 files and you copy something into it's parent folder where the folder name is the same, and, let's imagine you are copying 3 files and at the end you want to end up with 5 files, let's make an example, like:

Original:

```
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileA
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileB
```

Stuff you want to copy:

```
locale/fileC
locale/fileD
locale/fileE
```

When you copy it into `~/User/abc/Documents/` you get this:

[image]

There is no option to **COPY** / **MERGE** ! if you press REPLACE you will end up with:

```
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileC
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileD
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileE
```

instead of

```
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileA
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileB
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileC
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileD
~/User/abc/Documents/locale/fileE
```

What is going on here? How can I simple merge the stuff I want with the existing one. Like [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) asks

[image]

Comment: +1. Would love to know **why**. Of note this has been standard practice with **Finder** since the early 90s if not all the way back. `cp` on the command line merges just fine.

Comment: it's pretty sad isn't it?  such a simple thing that can cause so many headaches... including destroyed data!!!  I think the question is a litte too open-ended though.  Maybe change it to something like "how can I copy with merge rather than replace?"

Comment: Don't drag the folder—instead, drag just the files. That should give you the results you want.

Comment: @Dori: true, but this really sucks when you have a bunch of folders underneath the folders you want to merge :/

Comment: In general I think of this as a feature rather than a flaw.  It seems very strange to me to expect that two folders will be merged seamlessly.  As a programmer, I often want to remove old/obsolete files, and a merge would not do that.

Comment: @Chealion:  When you say "cp on the command line" merges just fine, I was surprised.  But, "cp -R a/* b/" does appear to merge a/subdir into b/subdir in some way.  I'm not sure I trust it.  Note that when you use mv instead of cp, you get an error message.

Comment: @khedron I learned it merged when I attempted to have it do a replacement and wondered why things went screwy with a project I was working on. It merged perfectly much to my assumption's chagrin.

Comment: @Chealion:  Heh!  That's funny.

Comment: Yes, it's a feature. The reason I could think of is that some directories are actually containers (`.app`, `.bundle`, `.kext`) and "merging" by default would be catastrophic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We (the OS X users) have been asking ourselves that question since the age of dawn.

Very well phrased question to a sad response: OS X doesn’t do that and can’t do it without 3rd party tools.

Of the 3rd party alternatives there are a lot, I’ll just go ahead and recommend what I think it’s the best alternative to Finder, but… your mileage may vary.

[Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) by CocoaTech is not a free alternative (far from it) but it definitively addresses most of Finder shortcomings and adds a lot of nice things for the same price.

If you feel more adventurous, you can go ahead and see different alternatives and their prices [right here](http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/10/08/10-os-x-finder-alternatives-compared-and-reviewed/).

*Update*: Back in September 2010 [TotalFinder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/) didn't exist, but it's a very nice add-on that brings Tabs, Cut, Folder Reorder, etc. to the Finder. Not free, but way smaller than Path Finder if that's what you're looking for.

Let’s hope that 10.7 brings a new paradigm where questions like these are not relevant anymore :)

Comment: Path Finder is really great, thank you for point it out, to bad thought that Apple is focus to much on mobile (witch is great, dont understand me wrong) and leave us desktop users with this kind of behavior :(

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's because of Mac OS X way of handling certain packages.

For instance, an **application**. To the user, it's just an *.app* file, you double click it and it opens the app.
But really, it's a folder with .app extension, with a hierarchy like this:

[image: safari app mac-ox-x]

You can see that for yourselves by righ-clicking the app and choosing "Show Package Content".

The only reason I see for Apple not to allow merge on folder is that they didn't want to confuse the user. Like asking to merge when all you want is updating an application.
And since it's a standard way to represent packages on a Mac OS X system, they didn't bother trying to differentiate between packages and simple folders.

Comment: A valid reason, but other “exceptions” like that didn’t stop apple from ‘hardcoding’ the behavior into the Finder, so I don’t see how they couldn’t simply replace App bundles “behind the scenes”.

Comment: I agree that Apple didn't want to confuse users, but I think the package argument is irrelevant... Folders and Packages are already handled differently. In fact a package is not the same as a folder. Both are *directories*, but they packages and folders are treated differently in the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Most probably too late for all your replaced files, but copy the folder (<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) and then paste the items (<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>), it will then ask to merge

Answer (score 2):

Whip out your trusty terminal and and do:

```
prompt>cp -R locale ~/User/abc/Documents/
```