# OS X: Is there a way to change the default behavior of copy/move overwrite?

Tags: macos, finder, uti

Problem: Many of my friends are moving to OS X and are frustrated that, unlike Windows and *NIX systems, copying/moving a folder (with sub-folders) deletes the destination folder **if** a folder of the same name already exists at the destination.

Question: Is there a way to hack the system (or install a plugin?) so that it by default copy/move operations **merge** the source and destinations instead of outright wiping out the destination and everything inside (with no option for recovery)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does copy replace stuff instead of merging it?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/why-does-copy-replace-stuff-instead-of-merging-it)

Comment: Exact duplicate of that question :-)

Comment: Well, not exactly. The accepted solution suggests a complete Finder replacement, which are generally not free. I'm looking for a system hack just to get around this one "feature".

Comment: There is no "system hack", you'll need to install third party software or use unix tools.

Comment: How can you be so sure? Are you the whole world? Unix is running down below, there's _gotta_ be a way! _\*naivelook\*_ ;)

Comment: @glenneroo: regardless, if there is, it would show up as an answer to the other, duplicate of this question :)

Comment: @glenneroo: There's nothing built in to the OS that supports this. Sure, I could be wrong, but I am 99.99% sure that you'll need third party software for this. A good portion of "system hacks" are actually properties which can be enabled with the `default` command, and there's nothing under there that does what you want. :-(

Comment: Fair enough. Is it OK if I leave this open, in hopes that one day some hacker-hero will ride in and save the day?

Comment: @glenneroo: of course.  we can't force you to close your own question.  on the other hand, voters or a mod might do so :P

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Based on your clarification, you're looking to merge two directories. [See this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/why-does-copy-replace-stuff-instead-of-merging-it) for more information. There's no built-in way to do that using the OS X Finder.

As an alternative, you could try using standard unix tools like `rsync`, which are available via the command line. But this is not a very "Mac like" solution.

---

I'm not sure what you're asking, because when you copy a folder from one place to the other, nothing is deleted at all. I assume you're talking about copying a folder from one location to another where *a folder of the same name already exists at the destination*? If so, The Mac OS X Finder will show you a warning, it won't delete anything without your permission.

[image: Example]

If that's not what you're asking, please edit your question to clarify, and comment on this answer asking me to update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I added clarification :) Yes it warns you, but merging is what i'm after here. In Windows you also get a warning (and a warning for every file/sub-folder) before you over-write something. OSX outright deletes EVERYTHING at the destination.