# Folder copy without losing any existing files

Tags: finder, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does “Copy” replace stuff instead of merging it?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/why-does-copy-replace-stuff-instead-of-merging-it)

In Windows, if I overwrite a folder `abc/doc` to `def/doc`, (1) files existing in `abc/doc` but not in `def/doc` are simply added to `def/doc`; (2) files existing in `def/doc` but not in `abc/doc` do not change; and (3) files existing in both folders are replaced. But in Mac, all files in `def/doc` are deleted and files in `abc/doc` are copied. I am not talking about which should be the more correct behavior, but was wondering if Mac can be tuned to how Windows behave, because I am more comfortable with such behavior.

I found that Lion now behaves just like Windows, but in Snow Leopard or older version, how can I make Mac OS behave like what I described?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot accomplish this using the Finder. A third-party solution like [Path Finder](http://www.cocoatech.com/) could be what you're looking for. Path Finder can merge on paste.